# Make pop-up Windows on Phone application always stay in the center of the screen

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, popup

I have an application in Windows Phone and some information is displayed on several popups, in some cases the height and width is set automatically according to screen sizes. I want to show this popup throughout the center of the screen regardless of whether the user scrolls the page up or down, scrollviewer.
I tried to make vertical and horizontal center but that is not working. Noting that the application is Windows Phone 8.
I could do this depending on the location of the cursor when I click it to open in the center. Please excuse me if I made the wrong solution, a little help please. Thank you!

Comment: Any solution, My application is in windows phone 8.0, I try different cases, I put pop up on center screen, but no change location